# Copying a symbolic link in Python

Tags: python, symlink

I want to copy a file `src` to the destination `dst`, but if `src` happens to be a symbolic link, preserve the link instead of copying the contents of the file. After the copy is performed, `os.readlink` should return the same for both `src` and `dst`.

The module `shutil` has several functions, such as `copyfile`, `copy` and `copy2`, but all of these will copy the *contents* of the file, and will not preserve the link. `shutil.move` has the correct behavior, other than the fact it removes the original file.

Is there a built-in way in Python to perform a file copy while preserving symlinks?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Python 3 `follow_symlinks`**

In Python 3, most copy methods of `shutil` have learned the `follow_symlinks` argument, which preserves symlinks if selected.

E.g. for `shutil.copy`:

```
shutil.copy(src, dest, follow_symlinks=False)
```

and [the docs say](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy):

> ```
> shutil.copy(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True)
> ```
>
> Copies the file src to the file or directory dst. src and dst should be strings. If dst specifies a directory, the file will be copied into dst using the base filename from src. Returns the path to the newly created file.
>
> If `follow_symlinks` is false, and src is a symbolic link, dst will be created as a symbolic link. If follow_symlinks` is true and src is a symbolic link, dst will be a copy of the file src refers to.

This has one problem however: if you try to overwrite an existing file or symlink, it fails with:

```
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'b' -> 'c'
```

unlike the `follow_symlinks=True` which successfully overwrites.

The same also happens for `os.symlink`, so I ended up using instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import shutil
import os

def copy(src, dst):
    if os.path.islink(src):
        if os.path.lexists(dst):
            os.unlink(dst)
        linkto = os.readlink(src)
        os.symlink(linkto, dst)
    else:
        shutil.copy(src, dst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.symlink('c', 'b')
    os.symlink('b', 'a')
    copy('a', 'b')

    with open('c', 'w') as f:
        f.write('a')
    with open('d', 'w'):
        pass
    copy('c', 'd')
    copy('a', 'c')
```

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10, Python 3.6.7.

Answer (score 48):

Just do

```
def copy(src, dst):
    if os.path.islink(src):
        linkto = os.readlink(src)
        os.symlink(linkto, dst)
    else:
        shutil.copy(src,dst)
```

[shutil.copytree](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) does something similar, but as senderle noted, it's picky about copying only directories, not single files.

Comment: I tried using `copytree` to do this and I got an OSError complaining that `src` wasn't a directory; I think checking `os.path.islink` really is the only way.

Comment: It think it's weird there's no dedicated function for copying files (rather than directories like copytree does) that preserves symlinks rather than resolving  them, but I couldn't find any either. It seems like this is the only way...

Comment: Note that in python 3, an additional keyword `follow_symlinks=True|False` was added to most of the shutil functions. Your answer works for creating the link, but also keeping the metadata could be nice. `shutil.copystat()` also tries to resolve the source if it's a symlink by default (and borks with ENOENT on broken links), but I'm not sure about the concise way to copy that metadata for symlinks in python2.

Comment: It is very important to call `shutil.copytree(src, dst, symlinks=True)` if you want symlinks to be preserved in the destination dir.