# Python: Copying symlink folders/files in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to copy folders from one location to other. Here, I have two folders test/ , sanity/ which are symlinks to other folders.

When i try to copy, Those two folders are not copied as links. Instead, They are copying as normal directories.

i am using python 2.7 and trying to use 'shutil.copytree'

```
build_path=/home/usb/builds/
build_folders = os.listdir(build_path) 
for folder in build_folders:
   src_path=os.path.join(build_path,folder)
   dst_path=os.path.join(Temp_dir,folder)
   shutil.copytree(src_path,dst_path,symlinks=True)
```

`/home/usb/builds/` has folders which needs to copy. Here is the list below.

```
   test -> usb/test
   sanity -> usb/sanity
   usb
   logs
   libraries
```

Above test, sanity is softlinks. They were copying as normal directories.

Can you please help?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847615/copying-a-symbolic-link-in-python)

Comment: shutle.copy works only for files right ? It wont works for directories.